# How to extract one of the properties from an object as an array in PHP?

Tags: php, array

I have an object that looks like below. I would like to pull out just the "DID" property as an array. How would I go about that in PHP?

```
stdClass Object
(
[t] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [DID] => 0722459
                [ForwardingNumber] => 13479330
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [DID] => 072562
                [ForwardingNumber] => 1443997
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [DID] => 0722876
                [ForwardingNumber] => 1845638
            )
```

Comment: pls write correct format. this is giving error.

Comment: Ok I updated. Thank you

Comment: use getData() then print here whatever comes up

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with $myObject being the object):

`$myObject = (array)$myObject;
$dids = array_column($myObject['t'], 'DID');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_map` method of PHP here.

```
function mapper($obj){
    return $obj->DID;
}

$dids = array_map("mapper", $yourObject->t);
```